# Search a google map I have created and embedded into my website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google map I have created to highlight the location of several support groups by adding my own pins using my maps and embedding this into my website.

Is there a Google widget of any description to allows people to search my custom map and find their nearest support group (or nearest pin).

I have read through the Google maps stuff but cant seem to find anything that meets my requirements.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map has no clue about which markers or overlays you have put on it. Therefore there are no way you can do what you want using Google Maps directly. You can however do something else.

When you create your markers/overlays and place them on the map you can add them to an array. When you users then enters a location you can search through that array to find the markers that are closest to the location the user has entered. Google Maps API has a method for getting the distance between two latlngs, but you can also use an ordinary Haversine formula for calculating it.

Once you have found the closest markers it is not hard making sure they are the only ones that are shown on the map.